# How to solve the insert problem of json data in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a table called "rules" in this table it has 3 columns and subjects are a ***JSON*** type column. Now in my form, there is two **select** list. One is select2 and another one is normal select list. So when  want to insert columns it will not saving. Please help me to solve the problem.
My controller

```
public function store(DepartmentRequest $request)
    {
        $department=new Department;
        $department->name=$request->name;
        $department->minimum=$request->minimum;
        $department->slug=$request->slug;
        $department->save();
        if ($request->range && $request->total) {
            $exceed=$request->range + $request->total;
            if ($exceed > 100) {
                return back();
            }
        }
        if($request->subject_id && $request->range)
        {
            $rule = new Rule();
            $arr_tojson = json_decode(json_encode($request->subject_id),TRUE);
            $rule->department_id=$department->id;
            $rule->range=$request->range;
            $rule->save();
        }
        if($request->id && $request->total)
        {   
            $rule = new Rule;
            $arr_tojson = json_decode(json_encode($request->id),TRUE);
            $rule->subject_id=$arr_tojson;
            $rule->department_id=$department->id;
            $rule->range=$request->total;
            $rule->save();
        }
        return redirect('departments');

    }
```

My model

```
class rule extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['subject_id','department_id','range'];

    protected $casts=['subject_id' => 'array'];
   }
```

Please, someone, help me to insert it into rule table.

dd($request->subject_id)

[image]

dd($request->id)
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a `var_dump($request->subject_id)` ? thank you

Comment: $request->subject_id
it only contain one data and $request->id contain multiple data as its come fro select2. BTW i will post the result of both $requests.Please wait a second

Comment: Why are you doing json_encode() inside json_decode()?

Comment: i just  show a laracasts posts thats why. And i am new with json works

Comment: If you put `name="subject_id[]"` on the <select2> you will receive the subjct_id as an Array.

Comment: yes i already put that in  <select2>but i cant insert it in database

Comment: `$arr_tojson = json_encode($request->id);` would be correct. It's back as an array by wrapping it json_decode()

Comment: $arr_tojson = json_encode($request->id); 
            $rule->subject_id=$arr_tojson;
i put this but no luck

Comment: Are you sure `if($request->id && $request->total)` is true? You don't use `$arr_tojson ` in the other `if`

Comment: if($request->id && $request->total),yes theres something wrong

Comment: i will put in 24 but in dd it shows null,why it will sow this result

Comment: <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" name="total" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('total') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="Enter Marks">
                </div>

Comment: here is my html code and in controller i tried this dd($request->total); but i dont know which value it shows